# XSLT Rendering HTML br tags inconsistently

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml, itext

I am observing inconsistent behavior when applying XSL that is rendering html. My specific questions are after the code blocks below.

**XML Instance:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1>
        <child2>XXXXXX</child2>
    </element1>
</root>
```

**My simple XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title>Test Instance</title>
      </head>   
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/element1/child2"/>
        <br/>
        NBSP = '&#160;'
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//element1"/>
      </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="//element1">
      Call From Template:
      <br/>
      <xsl:value-of select="./child2"/>
      <br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My Resulting output**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>Test Instance</title>
   </head>
   <body>XXXXXX<br></br>
                NBSP = '&nbsp;'
                <br></br>
            Call From Template:
            <br xmlns="">XXXXXX<br xmlns=""></body>
</html>
```

So my two specific questions are as follows:

1. The 'br' tags that are rendered by the root template are consistently
   being closed in the rendered output, while those rendered from the applied transform are not. My understanding of the way it was supposed to render is that all of the 'br' tags would remain open. **Can anyone explain why this occurs?** If I change the output method to 'xhtml' with saxon he 9.0.3.5 or 'xml' with any other parser, it renders the 'br' tags consistently by closing all of them.
2. My second question relates to the handling of the non-blocking space ( ) inserted into the html output. When rendered as output and using the default UTF-8 encoding, it displays the non-breaking space explicitly with **&nbsp;** whereas specifying the output as xhtml or xml cause the space to be rendered as C2 A0, which is the UTF-8 representation of the non breaking space. Are there any ideas as to why it renders it as UTF-8 for xhtml and not for html? While I'm guessing that this is because of the way xhtml is supposed to parse versus html, I am finding that certain xhtml parsers (in particular, the iText XMLWorker) doesn't properly decode the non breaking space represented as a UTF-8 code and I'm trying to figure out how to work around it.

Thanks

Comment: WRT #2, XML files are defined as having UTF-8 by default (unless you emit an XML declaration changing it) so it shouldn't matter, and the transformation thinks it's being efficient. C2 A0 is shorter than "&#160;". Let's see what I can come up with. I'm also not sure I like the `xmlns=""` in the bottom two `br` elements.

Comment: By the way, this sounds like it's two different problems, so it might have been better off as two separate questions. Unless we can find a solution that solves both of them at once.

Comment: How are you retrieving the output? I get `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><title>Test Instance</title></head><body>XXXXXX<br>
        NBSP = '&nbsp;'
        <br>
      Call From Template:
      <br>XXXXXX<br></body></html>` with normal `br`s.

Comment: There is a fundamental inconsistency in your stylesheet. `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` declares that you are outputing xhtml in an xml format. So for xhtml, you should choose method="xml". If you intent html 5, then you should not use the xhtml namespace. It is not clear what your intended output format is: html? or xthml.

Comment: (1) In html, In the //element1 template you are outputing <br/> in the null namespace; but in the `match="/"` template, you are outputint <br/> in the xhtml namespace. THESE ARE COMPLETELY DIFFERENT. This explains the difference.

Comment: (2) `&nbsp;` is a predefined html entity. It is not a predefined xml entity. This is why you get `&nbsp;` with html method, and not for the xml method.

Comment: Also (2), If your xml parsing tools are worth anything, they should be able to cope with any valid encoding of the nbsp character. However, if not, and upgrading to XSLT 2.0 is an option, and you still need xhtml output, rather than html, consider the `xsl:character-map` instruction.

Comment: @Mr , Actually it was two different questions that were observed at the same time. I had debated placing two separate posts but decided against it because the same XSL illustrated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the HTML output method, a `br` element is treated specially (rendered as `<br>`) only if it is in no namespace.

With the XHTML output method, a `br` element is treated specially (rendered as `<br />`) only if it is in the XHTML namespace.

This changes with XSLT 3.0 which supports method="html" version="5", where "no namespace" and "XHTML namespace" are both accepted.

Comment: This explains it pretty well. When taken in conjunction with the post by @sean, it's a pretty comprehensive answer and not only answers my question but allows me to work around the limitations with the parser.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### XSLT 2.0, html output

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test Instance</title>
      </head>   
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/element1/child2" />
        <br/>
        NBSP = '&#160;'
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//element1" />
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//element1">
  Call From Template:
  <br />
  <xsl:value-of select="./child2" />
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

### XSLT 2.0, xhtml output, forcing &nbsp; (not a good idea)

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" use-character-maps="a" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:character-map name="a">
  <xsl:output-character character="&#160;" string="&amp;nbsp;"/>
</xsl:character-map>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test Instance</title>
      </head>   
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/element1/child2" />
        <br/>
        NBSP = '&#160;'
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//element1" />
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//element1">
  Call From Template:
  <br />
  <xsl:value-of select="./child2" />
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

### XSLT 2.0, xhtml output, the proper way

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test Instance</title>
      </head>   
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/element1/child2" />
        <br/>
        NBSP = '&#160;'
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//element1" />
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//element1">
  Call From Template:
  <br />
  <xsl:value-of select="./child2" />
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

### XSLT 1.0, xhtml output

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test Instance</title>
      </head>   
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/element1/child2" />
        <br/>
        NBSP = '&#160;'
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//element1" />
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//element1">
  Call From Template:
  <br />
  <xsl:value-of select="./child2" />
  <br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Where you produce XHTML using XSLT 2.0, I think you should be putting result tree elements into the XHTML namespace.